# does not updating database fields in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

does not updating database fields in laravel

into model

```
public function updateSport($sportDetail){

updateorCrate
```

}

when updating it should update because I'm getting the new records into console but it does not allow to update the fields i don't know why please suggest where i am mistaking. Thanks in advance

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: instead of manually adding fields you can use `updateOrCreate()` method

Comment: No error i found ok result

Comment: @jaysingkar i did updateOrCreate that does not work as well

Comment: attributes:protected showing the updating value
while
original:protected shows up the older value

Comment: when i am using $sportsModel = new UserSport;
  foreach($sports as $sport){
   $sportsModel->updateSport($sport);
   die;
  }

Comment: if i die it update first value if i remove die it does not update any more

Comment: can you check if your variable is correct..
`var_dump($result->toArray())`. in case of updating.

Comment: I think you are not getting your model `$result` properly

Comment: you are able to create but not able to update right ?

Comment: yes correct.. i think there is in problem with loop updated question pls check

Comment: yes .. I think the same.... that's why try var_dump(), it will clear the doubts. Post its op here

Comment: getting correct html form data and values using var_dump($result->toArray());

Comment: so you are getting the model you need as `$result`. right ?

Comment: yes see array that i want post into model updated question

Comment: as you can see you are getting multiple entries

Comment: but you want to update specific entry. right ?

Comment: yes correct specific based on sport_id and user_id

Comment: but your result is fetching multiple results

Comment: the op you posted is vardump for $result right ? It should have only one entry and not multiple entries

Comment: yes the same multiple records need to store

Comment: sorry didnot understand

Comment: I'm confused..... This is what I understand....
in your `updateSport($sportDetail)` method
$sportDeatils is an array consisting of values for 1 sport
$result in your above method is the model you want to update, so that must be a single result. right ? and the var_dump you provided does not look like of $result at all

Comment: I'm so sorry .. maybe I'm misunderstanding something.. It would be great if you could explain your requirement once again

Comment: updateSport($sportDetail) var_dump
<b>array</b> <i>(size=17)</i>
  'user_id' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'37913'</font> <i>(length=5)</i>
  'sport_id' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'1'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
  'position_id' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'2'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
 'team_name' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Hockey Team Name G2 hh'</font> <i>(length=22)</i>

Comment: 'shot' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'R'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>

Comment: <b>array</b> <i>(size=17)</i>
  'user_id' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'37913'</font> <i>(length=5)</i>
  'sport_id' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'2'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
  'position_id' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'9'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>

Comment: that to be posted give above @jaysingkar var_dump and posted array are same it has same values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call a new instance of the UserSport model for each iteration.

```
      foreach ($sports as $sportDetail) {
        $sportsModel =  UserSport::firstOrNew(array('user_id' => $sportDetail['user_id'], 'sport_id' => $sportDetail['sport_id'] ));
        $sportsModel->position_id =  $sportDetail['position_id'];
        $sportsModel->shot =   (isset($sportDetail['shot'])) ? $sportDetail['shot'] : '';
        .
        .
        .
        .
        $sportsModel->save();
    }
```

Comment: @James try that way

Comment: It will just create the post not update the same I wanted to update